# ReactJs : create html for multiple components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I am referring following example for isomorphic example of react.

https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example

If I disable javascript in browser then page gets rendered from server side and add button is not working.

Another Question is in server.js file html is getting generated with React.renderToStaticMarkup . In this example only one react component is there so data is passed to that component. What if I have more than 1 component and I have to pass data to each component. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @remus https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example in this example app.js contains only one react component. so we are passing data to that component in server.js file . My question is how to pass data if there are more than one component.

Comment: @remus content is rendered from server side so list elements are getting rendered properly but button's disabled attribute is set in componentDidMount and render. so button should also be enabled.